# cppcheck seems to work but no lint results appear (Subilme Text 3, Mac)

Tags: c++, macos, sublimetext3, cppcheck, sublimelinter

I'm using Sublime Text 3(Version 3.1.1, build 3176) on macOS High Sierra(Version 10.13.3).

I want to make `SublimeLinter-cppcheck` plugin & `cppcheck` work in my Sublime Text 3, so I installed them according to [this link](https://cppstartingkitproject-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/C++_Starting_Kit_Plugin--Recommandation--Prerequisite--Install_Cppcheck--How.html) and other web sites.

Now my `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` is like this.
(I also use the plugin for Python, so there are settings for flake8.)

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "linters": {
    "cppcheck": {
      "@disable": false,
      "source": "source.cpp",
      "lint_mode": "save",
      "args": [],
      "enable": "style",
      "excludes": [],
      "std": ["c++11"]
    },
    "flake8": {
      "@disable": false,
      "source": "source.py",
      "args": ["--ignore=E111"],
      "enable": "style",
      "excludes": [],
    }
  },
}
```

Then I check whether they were successfully installed or not with `test.cpp` which is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "it works" << endl;

    return 0;
```

This code has apparently an error, so if they were successfully installed, some lint results will appear in the code.

In the debug console, cppcheck seems to be working, so I think I succeeded to install it. Here is the output of debug console.

```
SublimeLinter: sublime_linter.py:249: Delay buffer 28 for 0.1s
SublimeLinter: sublime_linter.py:249: Delay buffer 28 for 0.0s
SublimeLinter: linter.py:798: Checking lint mode background vs lint reason on_save
SublimeLinter: #98 linter.py:818: 'cppcheck' is linting 'test.cpp'
SublimeLinter: #98 linter.py:1174: Running ...

  /Users/ASHIJANKEN/Desktop  (working dir)
  $ /usr/local/bin/cppcheck --template=gcc --inline-suppr --quiet --std=c++11 --enable=style /Users/ASHIJANKEN/Desktop/test.cpp

SublimeLinter: #98 linter.py:866: cppcheck output:
    /Users/ASHIJANKEN/Desktop/test.cpp:6:0: warning: Invalid number of character '{' when no macros are defined. [syntaxError]
    {
    ^
SublimeLinter: #98 linter.py:906: cppcheck: No match for line: '{'
SublimeLinter: #98 linter.py:906: cppcheck: No match for line: '^'
SublimeLinter: sublime_linter.py:432: Linting buffer 28 took 0.03s
```

However, no lint result is appear in editing window.

[image: An image of actual window when I editing test.cpp]

I don't know why lint results don't appear.  Where did I made mistakes?

I know that cppcheck doesn't work when lint_mode is background([Related issue](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-cppcheck/issues/10)). is it related to this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment, finally I solved this problem with deleting the section below from `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings`.

```
"cppcheck": {
  "@disable": false,
  "source": "source.cpp",
  "lint_mode": "save",
  "args": [],
  "enable": "style",
  "excludes": [],
  "std": ["c++11"]
},
```

Now my `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` is shown below.

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "linters": {
    "flake8": {
      "@disable": false,
      "source": "source.py",
      "args": ["--ignore=E111, E114"],
      "enable": "style",
      "excludes": [],
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: I've got the same problem. How did you solve this exactly? I don't get what you mean by "...with deleting the section below from SublimeLinter.sublime-settings". How does your user-settings-file look now?

Comment: I updated my answer, so please check it. I just deleted the `cppcheck` section. I think this affected the correct behavior.

Comment: Ok thx.my issue was different. I installed cppcheck via ubuntus package manager.this gave me cppcheck version 1.8x and apparently this version did not provide a "column"-output. After downloading and building cppcheck version 1.90 everything is fine